# Is there a native StackOverflow.com app for iPad/iOS?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

Is there a native app for Stack Overflow for iPad/iOS?

The site's not too bad on iPad via the browser, but it's also a bit of a pain to use at times.

Answer (score 3):

[Full list is available](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/ipad).
Due to current API limitations they allow read-only access to the Stack Exchange sites.